# Find rows with multiple reference values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been struggling with this problem. Head against the wall. I know this has to be easy.

I want to select items that match multiple criteria on a reference table. Here is a example schema that can help illustrate the problem

```
tblCars
------------
CarID
CarName

tblCarColors
------------
ColorID
Color

tblCarColorXRef
------------
ID
CarID
ColorID
```

Basically, I want to find cars with multiple colors that I'm searching against. To continue the example. Let's say Toyota in the car table is multi-colored.. black and yellow

CarID of the Toyota would be 1

ColorID for black is 1 and yellow would be 2

I need to find all cars in the tblCarColorXRef table that match 1 AND 2. Has to be 'and'. I don't want to find cars that are black or cars that are yellow, but cars that contain both yellow and black.

The problem, is that I can search WHERE ColorID = 1 AND ColorID = 2. That would never be true, so this is where the head banging starts. I need to wrap this query with other criteria from other tables, I get close with HAVING and COUNT but, that is not necessarily accurate or correct.

Side note... cars can have 1 or many colors with the XRef table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
select carid
  from tblCarColorXRef
 where colorid in (1,2)
 group by carid
having count(colorid = 2);
```

You can use `count(disinct colorid) = 2`, if the car, color combination is not unique.

Comment: Sweet. I'm assuming COUNT(ColorID = ) would increment depending on the amount within the IN?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a couple of other things.

1. Remove "tbl" from the table names.
2. Try to get rid of the ID columns -- in this example they wouldn't be necessary as Types of cars is the actual key you're looking for (Honda, Toyota, etc..) - Same with Colors.  This may help your Xref as well - which would have a composite key as the primary key and not an ID column.  See if this helps - [CarColorExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0fb67/1), if not, give me more information and I'll revise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit rusty with SQL so I might be overlooking something (e.g. syntax error or logic error), but this might help you get started. This is what I'd try:

Select those `CarID`s which have at least one instance in the same table with `ColorID` 1 and one instance in the same table with `ColorID` 2.

```
SELECT a.CarID
FROM tblCarColorXRef a
WHERE
(
    SELECT COUNT(1) AS carsWithColor1
    FROM tblCarColorXRef b
    WHERE b.CarID = a.CarID AND b.ColorID = 1
    LIMIT 1
) > 1
AND
(
    SELECT COUNT(1) AS carsWithColor2
    FROM tblCarColorXRef b
    WHERE b.CarID = a.CarID AND b.ColorID = 2
    LIMIT 1
) > 1
```